# how to catch c++ builtin exception object

Tags: c++

I have a issue when i try to catch exception when i am calling a method.

So i have a method where i am throwing exceptions in a cpp file:

```
char className::createSmth()
{
 char l_char;
 Type l_variable;
 Type *pointer1 = l_variable.add_smth();
 if (nullptr == pointer1)
{
  throw std::runtime_error("pointer 1 is null");
}
else
{
 Type *pointer 2 = pointer1->methodCall();
if (pointer)
{
 //do smth;
}
else
{
throw std::runtime_error("pointer 2 is null"); 
}
}
return l_char;
}
```

And i want to handle those exceptions in another method and throw again an exception in catch block.

```
void className2::ExceptionsHandling(Type p_pointer)
{
Type *pointer3 = p_pointer->doSmth();

try
{
const Type l_localVariable = pointer3->createMessage();
}
catch(std::runtime error &e)
{
cout<< e.what()l
throw std::runtime_error("Throwing a exception to another method");
}

l_localVariable.Add(3);
}
```

But my compiler is saying that: 
error: 'l_localVariable' was not declared in this scope l_localVariable.Add(3).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, `l_localVariable` is local to the `try` block, so you can't use it outside. Just declare it outside. You'd have to make it non-const, but that's probably what you want, since you are calling `Add` on it, which seems like a modifying operation.

Comment: See, that in this code sequence: `... cout<< e.what()l \n throw ...`, there is an accidentially typed 'l'. This is an obvious syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

`try` block is a separate scope, so variables declared in `try` block are only visible there.

You can either use the object in `try` scope:

```
try
{
    const Type l_localVariable = pointer3->createMessage();
    l_localVariable.Add(3);
}
catch(std::runtime error &e)
{
    cout<< e.what();
    throw std::runtime_error("Throwing a exception to another method");
}
```

Or (if the above cannot be done for some reason), you need to declare a pointer type that will be initialized in `try` block:

```
std::unique_ptr<const Type> l_localVariable;
try
{
    l_localVariable = std::make_unique(pointer3->createMessage());
}
catch(std::runtime error &e)
{
    cout<< e.what();
    throw std::runtime_error("Throwing a exception to another method");
}

l_localVariable->Add(3);
```